# Preventing double booking and booking before today php pdo

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I have a booking form set up where the user can book different facilities but I can't get my head around how to prevent the user from booking a date that is before today or how to prevent them from double booking.

I did try and work with a datepicker but I am using the HTML5 standard datepicker and also using Twitter Bootstrap but I don't know how to restrict dates from the user.

Below includes my full form and the PHP included in it.

```
<?php
        include "config.php"; 

        //Booking point
        if(isset($_POST['booking']))
        {
            //get values for variables
            $pitchID = $_POST['pitchID'];
            $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
            $start_hour = $_POST['start_hour'];
            $end_hour = $_POST['end_hour'];
            $booking_age = $_POST['booking_age'];
            $pitch_size = $_POST['pitch_size'];
            $light_tokens = $_POST['light_tokens'];

            $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO booking SET pitchID = ?, start_date = ?, start_hour = ?, end_hour = ?, booking_age = ?, pitch_size = ?, light_tokens = ?");
            $query = $q->execute(array($pitchID,$start_date,$start_hour,$end_hour,$booking_age,$pitch_size,$light_tokens));

            $count = $q->rowCount();
                if($count == 0)
                {
                    echo "Your booking has been made";
                    header("Location:home2_template.html");
                    return; 
                }else {
                    echo "That booking already exists";
                }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: narrow down you code

Comment: The code that starts with isset(['booking']) starts my booking procedure

Comment: with "narrow down your code" I mean we dont need all the html

Comment: Oh no problem, sorry.  Edited now

Comment: Before you insert the new booking. You need to get dates from previous bookings. Once you have that you can compare those with the new booking. If the new booking isn't matching any of the previous bookings you can insert the new booking

Comment: I thought that was what my rowCount() would do.  It would check to see if there was going to be a duplicate booking and then return the 'booking already exists' statement

Comment: `rowCount()` shouldn't be relied upon.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php *"PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement."* - Use `count()` or set a UNIQUE constraint for the given column(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a date is before a certain date you could convert your dates to timestamp and check if one is lower than the other

```
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];

if( strtotime($start_date) < time()) {
    // Date is before today
} else {
    // Date is after today
}
```